# Сокет SocketException: Socket closed

Tags: java, сокет

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь сделать многопоточный клиент-сервер.
При попытке прочитать сообщение от клиента ловлю ошибку:
"Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed"

Сервер:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT)) {
        while (true) {
            Connect connect = new Connect(serverSocket);
            new Thread(() -> {
                connect.writeLine("Привет");
                String msg = connect.readLine(); **в этом месте падает ошибка**
                System.out.println(msg);
            }).start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Клиент

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Connect connect = new Connect(IP, PORT)) {

        String msg = connect.readLine();
        System.out.println(msg);
        while (true) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String message = scanner.nextLine();
            connect.writeLine(message);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Класс Connect

```
public class Connect implements Closeable {
private Socket socket;
private BufferedReader reader;
private BufferedWriter writer;

public Connect(String ip, int port) {
    try {
        this.socket = new Socket(ip, port);
        this.reader = createReader();
        this.writer = createWriter();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public Connect(ServerSocket serverSocket) {
    try {
        this.socket = serverSocket.accept();
        this.reader = createReader();
        this.writer = createWriter();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private BufferedReader createReader() {
    try {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private BufferedWriter createWriter() {
    try {
        return new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public void writeLine(String msg) {
    try {
        writer.write(msg);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public String readLine() {
    try {
       return reader.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Т.е. по какой-то причине сокет закрывается в тот момент когда я пытаюсь его использовать, как я это понимаю. Подскажите пожалуйста, где может быть причина возникновения проблемы?

Comment: Переменные надо объявлять в клкссе

Answer (score 0):

В лямбда-выражениях стоит использовать внешние (относительно выражения) неизменяемые значения, а не внешние переменные, значение и внутреннее состояние которых могут меняться. Под внешними неизменяемыми значениями, соответственно, подразумеваются effectively final локальные переменные и поля примитивных типов, а также effectively final объекты, внутреннее состояние которых не будет меняться.

Связано это с тем, что Streams и лямбда-выражения проектировались из расчета на их многопоточное использование.
Поэтому я считаю, что ваша проблема в захвате переменной connect в лямбде. Я могу ошибаться, но вы можете это легко проверить в своем коде, отказавшись от лямбды.
[Пример многопоточного сервера](https://habr.com/ru/post/357688/)